# error while using a factory to return data to controller

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie to angular and I am fetching data from json file using a service and then returning the data to controller. When i click the button the controller method is not getting executed and there are no errors in console.log. what am i missing here?

My service code:

**Service.js**

```
 app.factory('MovieService', function ($http) {
            var url = "js/data.json";
            var data;

            return {
                getData: function() {
                    return $http.get(url)
                        .success(function(response) {
                            data = response;
                            return data;

                        })
                        .error(function (error){
                            console.log("error");
                        })
                }
            };
        });
```

**Controller.js**

```
app.controller('MainController1', ['$scope', '$log','$location','MovieService', function($scope,$log,$location,MovieService) {

    console.log("click");
    var getData = function() {
            // This service's function returns a promise
            MovieService.getData()
                .then(function(data) {
                    // promise fulfilled
                   console.log("controller data");

                    $scope.custdata = data;
                    console.log($scope.custdata);

                }, function(error) {
                    // promise rejected, could log the error with: 
                    console.log("error");
                });
        };    


}])
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="MainController1 as main">

        <input type="button" name="getdata" value ="Get data" ng-click="main.getData ()"></input>

    </div>
```

**data**

```
[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "Harry Potter"
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Name": "Jurassic Park"
    }
]
```

Comment: controller method should be bounded to `this` like `this.getData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things should be notice:-

**1)** You should use this instead of var to bind the function to the controller in `controller as` syntax:-

this.getData = function() {//your logic}

**2)** You are wrapping promise twice first in `success()` or `error()` then in another `then()` function instead do it like this:-

In service:-

```
 getData: function() {
                    return $http.get(url);
                        
                }
```

In controller:-

```
 MovieService.getData()
                .then(function(response) {
                    // promise fulfilled
                   console.log("controller data");

                    $scope.custdata = response.data;
                    console.log($scope.custdata);

                }, function(error) {
                    // promise rejected, could log the error with: 
                    console.log("error");
                });
```

**3)** `<input>` should not close like `</input>` it is not having closing tag.

Hope it help :)

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/CH1rK2DSMa9SZfJwhcLe?p=preview)**

Comment: while running the plunker i am getting the error:http://run.plnkr.co/4diel6ZZjOWxbThp/data.json

Comment: plunker runs correctly why you added data.json at the end

Comment: @squirod, i want to filter the response data . for e.g i would like to filter based on id and then return data... do i have to write a seperate javascript function for this or is there any easier way in angular. for e.g filter based on movieid=1

Comment: No need for separate function, just iterate data in the then() and push it in the $scope.custdata based on Ids you want.

Comment: i tried something like this in the service angular.forEach(response)
      {
       // code
      } but throwing an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82285/discussion-between-squiroid-and-user2010243).

Comment: @Who so ever gave negative please comment why ? I want to know :P

Comment: can u let me know what i am missing in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264858/error-while-using-a-value-of-one-service-in-another

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind controller function on scope.

```
$scope.getData = function() { }"
```

instead

```
var getData = function() { }
```

and call it in template like

```
ng-click="getData ()"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `controller as alias` syntax.

In this case, your controller functions that need to be accessed from the view should be assigned to `this`.

So, define your function as a property of `this` and not as an independent function - like so:

```
this.getData = function () {...}
```

You are using `var getData` which will make the function a local function and not expose it.