# error while using a value of one service in another

Tags: angularjs

**UPDATE**

I am editing the query since i have resolved the earlier issue. There are 2 services - authentication and user and the filteration has to be done on the authentication service. This service is supposed to return the users from the json. the user service has to add other methods to give additional details of the user once fetched from the authentication service.

However i am not sure of the methodology i used to fetch the user details. I have injected both the services - authenticationService and user Service to the controller. Is there a better way of doing this.

I am not sure if this is the right way to ask the question. Kindly let me know if i have to modify this at any point of time.

```
The working copy is in the link below:
```

[PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/MFLLJ1iE7ypHTF4PMENs?p=preview)

Comment: could you include a plunker link please

Comment: @amo_geismar.. I have resolved the issue and i have the plunker link updated. I would like to know if this can be done more efficiently and in an optimized manner.